# Merge "indices" into "market-indexes" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[market-indexes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/market-indexes) (~150 questions):

> This is a metric for tracking a collection of securities. For example, among US stocks, a commonly referenced index is the S&P 500. An index may be price-weighted, market-capitalization weighted or some other way to determine how much of the index each security contributes.

[indices](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indices) (< 10 questions): no description.

Suggestion: merge these two tags. "market-indexes" should win.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pre-requisite for doing this is removal of [indices](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indices) where [market-indexes](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/market-indexes) wouldn't fit. I've just done that for these two questions.

[Is there a financial product that allows speculation on GDP?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/36401/is-there-a-financial-product-that-allows-speculation-on-gdp)

[Money Flow index (MFI) and deciding when money flow is positive or negative?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/22149/money-flow-index-mfi-and-deciding-when-money-flow-is-positive-or-negative)

If there are no arguments to the contrary soon I will merge the tags and make [indices](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/indices) into a synonym. [now done]